# How to increment fields in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have the following table Incontri:

[image: I have the following table Incontri:]

I want to update `IdIncontroInterno` with an increasing value;

When the turn is equal to 0 the `IdIncontroInterno` fields must have an increasing value. When the turn increases past 0 the following formula must be applied:

```
IdIncontroInterno = IdIncontroInterno + (2^Turn);
```

Additionally the idIncontroInterno counter must be reset.
I'm having problems with updating every IdIncontroInterno field while maintaining the "Auto_increment" value when the turn is equal to 0.

I create this (wrong) stored procedures..

```
BEGIN
declare done int default false;
declare turno_ int;
declare idIncontroInterno_ int default 1;
declare a int default 0;
declare cur1 cursor for select Turno, idIncontroInterno from Incontri;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;    
 open cur1;
 fetch cur1 into turno_, idIncontroInterno_;
     creaLoop : LOOP
             if done then
                 leave creaLoop;
             end if;
             set idIncontroInterno_ = idIncontroInterno_ + (2^turno_);
     end loop;
 close cur1;
```

This is the result that I want:
[image: This is the result that I want:]

Comment: Maybe try doing this in a function?

Comment: Please add your result to the answer not by a link.

Comment: I can't because this is the second question and for post the result to the answer you need to have more points.

Comment: RugerS19, sorry for the stupid question but to doing in a function what change from doing in a procedure?